# Why does this regex match anything

Tags: regex

The regular expression

```
\\(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.)
```

is used for latex syntax highlighting in Texworks.

Why does this expression matches anything besides `\`? As I understand, the lookahead is not matching anything (only checking if the condition is true). This expression is used to match Latex commands which usually are `\command` but also have special characters `\%,\|,...` hence the `.`in the regex.

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: `(?: ... )` is not a lookahead. It's a non-capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?:` is a non-capturing group. `?=` is a lookahead. The reason for the `(?:)` is so that the `|` applies to `[A-Za-z@]` and `.`. Without the `(?:)` the `|` would apply to `\\[A-Za-z@]` and `.`. This would match any string (because the `.` would always match), not just strings that have a `\` (more details on the matches follows). Since this is just a logical grouping to specify the scope of the `|` there is no need to keep the capture group which is why `?:` is used.

Looking at the regex:

`\\` means start matching with a `\`. Now, the string doesn't need to start with a `\` to match. The regex will match `\abc`, but it will also match the string `a\abc` where the match result will be `\abc` in both cases.

`[A-Za-z@]+` - `+` means one or more. So it matches one or more of the characters inside `[]`. This means that string such as `\a`, `\abc`, `\a@b` will be matched

`|` means OR.

`.` is any single character (not newline by default). This means that string such as `\a`, `\#`, `\,` will be matched. So the first character after the `\` can be any character, but if it does not match `[A-Za-z@]+` then the match will only match the first character. For example `\#a` will only match `\#`.

Examples of matches, where the match result is highlighted:

- `\abc@`
- ab`\abc@`
- ab`\abc@`#a
- `\#`abc@
- ab`\#`abc@#a

Examples of strings that will not match (note that these strings would have matched if the `(?:)` was removed)

- \
- abcabc

Comment: It is used for syntax highlighting. Latex commands have this syntax.

Comment: @ratatosk, I was more wondering what types of syntax would be highlighted, could you update your answer with some examples?

Comment: @ratatosk - see the updated examples in case they are helpful.

Comment: @ratatosk - also see the updated explanation of the `(?:)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In the given regex,

```
\\(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.)
```

`()` is a group operator. Regex treats the entries inside the group operator as a single unit.

So the regular expression accepts strings like,

`\.`, `\|`, `\a`, etc..

Moreover the regular expression will not accept `\` as such.

Comment: What does single unit mean here? Is that only for performance or does that change the behaviour (here). I found ways to insert options into this group, which makes sense, but as there are no options here, does this expression do anything different then `\\[A-Za-z@]+|.`?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is only going to match `\` and any character(s) directly following it.

1. The pattern matches the character \ literally
2. Next you have a non-capturing group `(?:[A-Za-z@]+|.)`
3. You also have another group which `.` matches any character (except newline).

There's no lookahead ahead, [here's a list of expressions](http://tacosw.com/latexian/help/find/regex.html) for reference.

[image]